How do I retrieve message that will be send from gateway to aws iot every 5 min using python
I create a python that will retrieve message from AWS IOT, the problem here is that the message that send by the gateway to aws iot is every 5 min, but my code keep reconnecting/subscribing making it retrieve the message every few seconds instead of 5 min. How do I fix this, so that I can retrieve the message from aws iot following the timestamp that the message arrive from the gateway.

def on_connection_interrupted(connection, error, **kwargs):
    print(f"Connection interrupted. Error: {error}")

def on_connection_resumed(connection, return_code, session_present, **kwargs):
    print(f"Connection resumed. Return code: {return_code}, session present: {session_present}")
    if return_code == mqtt.ConnectReturnCode.ACCEPTED and not session_present:
        print("Session did not persist. Resubscribing to existing topics...")
        resubscribe_future, _ = connection.resubscribe_existing_topics()
        resubscribe_future.add_done_callback(on_resubscribe_complete)

def on_resubscribe_complete(resubscribe_future):
    resubscribe_results = resubscribe_future.result()
    print(f"Resubscribe results: {resubscribe_results}")
    for topic, qos in resubscribe_results['topics']:
        if qos is None:
            sys.exit(f"Server rejected resubscribe to topic: {topic}")

def on_message_received(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain, **kwargs):
    global received_count
    received_count += 1
    
    print(f"Received message from topic '{topic}': {payload.decode()}")
    print(f"Count:{received_count}")
    
    timestamp = kwargs.get('timestamp', None)
    
    try:
        payload_str = payload.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(payload_str)
        
        timestamp = data.get('timestamp')
        
        if timestamp is not None:
            timestamp_seconds = timestamp / 1000
            dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_seconds)
        else:
            dt_object = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        insert_into_mysql(data.get('AHUList'), dt_object, mysql_config)

        if received_count == cmdData.input_count:
            received_all_event.set()
        
    except UnicodeDecodeError as decode_error:
        print(f"Error decoding payload: {decode_error}")
        
    except json.JSONDecodeError as json_error:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON payload: {json_error}")
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error occurred: {ex}")

def on_connection_success(connection, callback_data):
    assert isinstance(callback_data, mqtt.OnConnectionSuccessData)
    print(f"Connection Successful with return code: {callback_data.return_code}, session present: {callback_data.session_present}")

def on_connection_failure(connection, callback_data):
    assert isinstance(callback_data, mqtt.OnConnectionFailureData)
    print(f"Connection failed with error code: {callback_data.error}")

def on_connection_closed(connection, callback_data):
    print("Connection closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmdData = CommandLineUtils.parse_sample_input_pubsub()
    
    proxy_options = None
    if cmdData.input_proxy_host and cmdData.input_proxy_port:
        proxy_options = http.HttpProxyOptions(
            host_name=cmdData.input_proxy_host,
            port=cmdData.input_proxy_port
        )

    mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
        endpoint=cmdData.input_endpoint,
        port=cmdData.input_port,
        cert_filepath=cmdData.input_cert, 
        pri_key_filepath=cmdData.input_key, 
        ca_filepath=cmdData.input_ca, 
        on_connection_interrupted=on_connection_interrupted,
        on_connection_resumed=on_connection_resumed,
        client_id=cmdData.input_clientId,
        clean_session=False,
        keep_alive_secs=30,
        http_proxy_options=proxy_options,
        on_connection_success=on_connection_success,
        on_connection_failure=on_connection_failure,
        on_connection_closed=on_connection_closed
    )

    print(f"Connecting to {cmdData.input_endpoint} with client ID '{cmdData.input_clientId}'...")
    connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()

    connect_future.result()
    print("Connected!")

    message_topic = cmdData.input_topic

    print(f"Subscribing to topic '{message_topic}'...")
    subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
        topic=message_topic,
        qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
        callback=on_message_received
    )

    subscribe_result = subscribe_future.result()
    print(f"Subscribed with {str(subscribe_result['qos'])}")

    print("Disconnecting...")
    disconnect_future = mqtt_connection.disconnect()
    disconnect_future.result()
    print("Disconnected!")



I already try make the code wait for 5 min before execution, but its not the solution that I want.

I didn't fully understand what the issue is.
From what I see in code you provided, your script connects to an mqtt broker, subscribes to some topic and then without any waiting disconnects and exits.
The original code from the sample has a future for receiving messages, received_all_event. If you need your code to wait for a message, then try to use this variable.
